# How to use CMake to get command line output as an argument?

Tags: cmake, module, directory, header, lib

I'm using CMake to build linux module mode, so I'm retrieving header files on ubuntu, currently I'm running ubuntu in docker and it has:

```
/lib/modules/4.15.0-76-generic
```

Well, several days later if I build a new image, it will become updated value:

```
/lib/modules/4.15.0-78-generic
```

So this number is changing, but there's only one directory under /lib/module, and it's not 'uname -a' output.

```
Linux 0a08e87c0a18 4.15.0-50-generic
```

So I wish to know if there's a convenient way in CMake just like shell `ls /lib/module`, and then I can use command line output as a parameter for header/library root directory?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Using command [execute_process](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/execute_process.html) you may run(execute) arbitrary shell utility. A variable, which name is specified in `OUTPUT_VARIABLE` option, will contain output of that execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CMake's [`file(GLOB ...)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html#filesystem) command to list the contents (files and sub-directories) within a particular directory. If the `/lib/modules` directory only contains one sub-directory (and no files), you could do something like this:

```
file(GLOB MY_VERSIONED_DIR /lib/modules/*)
```

You can now use the `${MY_VERSIONED_DIR}` variable elsewhere in your CMake code, as it will be populated with the sub-directory path, for example:

```
/lib/modules/4.15.0-78-generic
```

---

You could also use CMake's [`execute_process()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/execute_process.html) command, which runs commands in a child process during CMake configure-time. Use the `OUTPUT_VARIABLE` argument to capture the output of your command:

```
if(UNIX)
    execute_process(
        COMMAND ls /lib/modules
        OUTPUT_VARIABLE MY_VERSIONED_DIR 
    )
endif()
```